# Error al insertar caracteres especiales como Ñ y acentos á, é, í, ó, ú. usando BULK OPENROWSET desde python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, sql-server-2008

Estoy teniendo problemas al insertar informacion a una tabla de mi base de datos SQLSERVER 2008 desde mi proyecto python haciendo uso OPENROWSET BULK y es que a pesar de que el archivo CSV genera bien caracteres especiales como Ñ, á, é, etc... al momento de insertarlo en la base de datos estos caracteres se dañan.

Aqui es donde creo mi archivo CSV:

`dfClientes.to_csv(cvs_path, index=False, sep=';', encoding='utf-8-sig')`

ejecuto un shutil copy para mover ese archivo a una ruta especifica

`shutil.copy(cvs_path, ruta_destinoCSV)`

y ejecuto el OPENROWSET BULK:

```
              bulk_insert_query = f'''INSERT INTO sgCliente (IdCliente,NomCliente,ApeCliente,NumDocumento,IdTipoDoc,NomTipoDoc,CodTipoDoc,Tip_docu,Sexo,FactorRh,GrupSangre,EstadoCivil,FecNacimiento,eMail,TelMovil,PrimerNombre,SegundoNombre,PrimerApellido,IndCentroExcelencia,IndDatosPersonal,IndHabilitado,IdTercero,CodUES)
                    SELECT * FROM  OPENROWSET(
                    BULK '{ ruta_destinoCSV }',
                    FORMATFILE='{ ruta_destinoXML }',
                    CODEPAGE = 'UTF-8-SIG',    
                    FIRSTROW = 2) as t
                '''
```

ESTE ES EL CONTENIDO DE MI ARCHIVO XML QUE USO COMO FORMATFILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <RECORD>
      <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="101" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="101" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="20" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="1" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="30" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="2" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="3" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="9" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="254" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="10" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="254" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="11" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="254" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="12" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="254" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="13" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="8"/>
      <FIELD ID="14" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="15" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="15" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="16" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="17" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="18" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="19" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="50" />
      <FIELD ID="20" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="50" />
      <FIELD ID="21" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="50" />
      <FIELD ID="22" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="50" />
      <FIELD ID="23" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='\r\n' MAX_LENGTH="5" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
   </RECORD>
   <ROW>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="IdCliente" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="NomCliente" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="ApeCliente" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="NumDocumento" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="IdTipoDoc" xsi:type="SQLTINYINT"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="NomTipoDoc" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="CodTipoDoc" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="8" NAME="Tip_docu" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="9" NAME="Sexo" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="10" NAME="FactorRh" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="11" NAME="GrupSangre" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="12" NAME="EstadoCivil" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="13" NAME="FecNacimiento" xsi:type="SQLDATETIME"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="14" NAME="eMail" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="15" NAME="TelMovil" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="16" NAME="PrimerNombre" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="17" NAME="SegundoNombre" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="18" NAME="PrimerApellido" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="19" NAME="IndCentroExcelencia" xsi:type="SQLBIT"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="20" NAME="IndDatosPersonal" xsi:type="SQLBIT"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="21" NAME="IndHabilitado" xsi:type="SQLBIT"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="22" NAME="IdTercero" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="23" NAME="CodUES" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
   </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

[Y ESTAN SON UNAS LINEAS DE MI ARCHIVO CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nearn.png)

[Y ASI SE VE EN MI BASE DE DATOS CUANDO TODO SE EJECUTA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeiYn.png)

ME PORIAN AYUDAR A AVERIGUAR COMO INSERTO CARACTERES ESPECIALES SIN QUE SE DAÑEN

Comment: No se mucho del tema, pero espero ayudar. Esos "caracteres dañados" son el resultado de que tu archivo está siendo leido con la codificación incorrecta. Basicamente, un caracter unicode como la ñ, que requiere más de un byte para representarse, se confunde por otro tipo de caracteres (presumiblemente de ascii). Esto me parece raro, ya que no parece haber indicios de que uses la codificación incorrecta. Posiblemente el problema está del lado de sql server. Te recomiendo revisar como hiciste el xml, la consulta y los tipos de columnas en tu tabla en base a lo dicho sobre la codificación.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, no se mucho sobre sql server, sin embargo cuando ejecuto un insert normal desde el proyecto de python e inserto `INSERT INTO sgCliente (IdCliente,NomCliente,ApeCliente) VALUES(362633,'ANDRÉS','PEÑA NIÑO ')`  la informacion carga correctamente a la tabla. Asi que supongo que el problema esta en el BULK OPENROWSET y en el archivo de formato, el cual extraje de la documentacion oficial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/xml-format-files-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Entonces estamos en la misma, no conzco sql server. Sin embargo, lo que mencioné de la codificación aplica a cualquier caso donde quieras abrir un archivo de texto plano, no solo a sql server.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta resulto ser bastante simple, SQL SERVER 2008 no tiene soporte para UTF-8, asi que hay que usar otro tipo de encoding al momento de generar el CSV de tal forma que el servidor de base de datos entienda, la respuesta es cambiar esta linea de codigo:

```
dfClientes.to_csv(cvs_path, index=False, sep=';', encoding='UTF-8-SIG')
```

por esto:

```
dfClientes.to_csv(cvs_path, index=False, sep=';', encoding='ANSI')
```